# how do i make a open close jquery button?

Tags: jquery

so i got this template that has a search bar when i click on it i get a popup that covers the page with the search results and the search bar unfortunantly i'm not really good at jquery and would like the button that opens this popup to also close it if i press it again.

```
//search popup
jQuery( ".search-popup" ).click(function() {
    jQuery(".search-pop-block").slideToggle(300);
    jQuery("body").addClass("body-hide");
});


//popup close
jQuery( ".pop-close" ).click(function() {
     jQuery(".search-pop-block").slideToggle(300);
     jQuery("body").removeClass("body-hide");
});
```

Comment: why are you then selecting different elements when you want to toggle using same button?

Comment: this is from the template i am trying to learn myself jquery at the moment and i know that i have to togle it somehow i just don't know how

Comment: `on it i get a popup that covers the page with the search result`-> if page is already covered how can you click on a button on page

Comment: the button is in the navigation bar that stays over the pop up

Comment: so in each case button is visible and you want that on click of the button itself pop-up will open/close. Am i right?

Comment: Is the button hidden behind an element?  regardless of whether the button is visible or not.

Comment: it wasn't no the problem has allready been resolved but thank you for wanting to help

Answer (score 0):

i found a way to make it work

```
jQuery( ".search-popup" ).click(function() {
    jQuery(".search-pop-block").slideToggle(300);
    jQuery("body")("addClass").toggleClass("removeClass");
});
```